# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" initializing Backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone collection something like the following:

```
var FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Foo,

    initialize: function (attributes, options) {
        this.barId = options.barId;
    }
});

var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

When I try to initialize this, I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in the `_prepareModel()` function of `Backbone.Collection`.

The bad call is in `model = new this.model(attrs, options)`.

```
// Prepare a model or hash of attributes to be added to this collection.
_prepareModel: function(model, options) {
  options || (options = {});
  if (!(model instanceof Model)) {
    var attrs = model;
    options.collection = this;
    model = new this.model(attrs, options); // <-- BLOWS UP HERE
    if (!model._validate(model.attributes, options)) model = false;
  } else if (!model.collection) {
    model.collection = this;
  }
  return model;
},
```

When I step through `_prepareModel()` in the debugger, it looks like the type of `this` at that point is `child`, and `this.model` is, in fact, undefined.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've updated the code sample to reflect the [assignment order problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14163206/27358).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my actual code `Foo` was declared after `FooCollection`. Didn't realize that Javascript doesn't support forward declarations. **[headdesk]**

Comment: Keep in mind that `var a = 6;` is two things in one: `var a;` and `a = 6;`. The `var` declaration will be hoisted to the top of the relevant scope but the assignment won't be.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem.  My problem was I had included my Model script after Collection Script:

```
<script src="scripts/collections/Classes.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/models/Class.js"></script>
```

To fix it I just had to move the Class.js up above Classes.js:

```
<script src="scripts/models/Class.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/collections/Classes.js"></script>
```

Cheers