# Backbone model attribute error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am simply just creating a collection and making a fetch call on it, but it is giving the following error. My backbone version is 1.1

I had done R&D on it also ( e.g [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162605/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-initializing-backbone-collecti) ) but still unable to figure the issue.

```
class MyApp.Collections.ProjectsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: MyApp.Models.Project
  url: '/projects'

class MyApp.Models.Project extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: 'project'
  idAttribute: 'objectId'

projects = new MyApp.Collections.ProjectsCollection()
projects.fetch( reset: true )
```

Here's the error which backbone show

```
// Prepare a model or hash of attributes to be added to this collection.
_prepareModel: function(attrs, options) {
  if (attrs instanceof Model) {
    if (!attrs.collection) attrs.collection = this;
    return attrs;
  }
  options || (options = {});
  options.collection = this;
  var model = new this.model(attrs, options);
  if (!model._validate(attrs, options)) return false;
  return model;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This .. 
projects.fetch( {reset: true} )